# TYPO3 Nested URLS for news categories

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-10.x

I’m coming to the end of my tether with how the URL system works. I don’t know if it is a compatibility issue with an extension I have installed, my understanding of the URL system in general or something else.

I have a plugin that displays, for want of a better word, called `tx_llcatalog_pi`  - this has the concept of filters and so, currently, the URL to filter looks like:

```
/news-publications/?tx_llcatalog_pi[filters][news]=814&tx_llcatalog_pi[filters][partnerships]=766&tx_llcatalog_pi[filters][themes]=800
```

The IDs are actually pages (this may be confusing TYPO3) which we use as categories. You can have 3 filters applied from different categories.

If I add the following routeEnhancer then it begins to work with nicer URLs:

```yaml
CatalogFilterNews:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/{type}/{partner}/{theme}'
    namespace: 'tx_llcatalog_pi'
    limitToPages: [450]
    defaults:
      type: 'all'
      partner: 'all'
      theme: 'all'
    _arguments:
      type: 'filters/news'
      partner: 'filters/partnerships'
      theme: 'filters/themes'
```

The URL generated is

```
/news-publications/817/all/all/
```

I can even update the routePath to something like `/type-{type}/partner-{partner}/theme-{theme}` and it works as expected (`/news-publications/type-817/partner-all/theme-all/` )

The problem comes when I try to use an aspect. As mentioned, each category is a page which has a title and custom “slug” url field which only contains the title, adding an aspect just creates a 404. (although generates the right URL: `/news-publications/consultation-responses/all/all/`)

```yaml
  CatalogFilterNews:
    type: Plugin
    routePath: '/{type}/{partner}/{theme}'
    namespace: 'tx_llcatalog_pi'
    limitToPages: [450]
    aspects:
      type:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: pages
        routeFieldName: tx_lltaxonomy_slug
      partner:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: pages
        routeFieldName: tx_lltaxonomy_slug
      theme:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: pages
        routeFieldName: tx_lltaxonomy_slug
    defaults:
      type: 'all'
      partner: 'all'
      theme: 'all'
    _arguments:
      type: 'filters/news'
      partner: 'filters/partnerships'
      theme: 'filters/themes'
```

Interestingly, if I reduce the logic to just 1 filter (e.g. type) with the aspect, it works

Any pointers would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Problem seem to be your defaults... If only *one* filter is set, the others are defaulting to 'all' - but there's no aspect, with matches tx_lltaxonomy_slug=='all'. So, the correct answer is 404

Comment: @JulianHofmann Interesting - I must be misunderstanding how the `defaults` work as I assumed it would look for a matching aspect and, if not, use "all". How would I handle that and tell it that "all" means leave empty?